# Strange behavior with displaying view in HTML

Tags: html, css, viewport

As shown in the picture below, the view, which is hidden when the div is initialized, does not display correctly.

[image]

The line should go up to the side of the div. There is nothing in the CSS that should affect that. Is that considered a normal behavior and I should change the viewport or something ?

For clarification, it is done with Angular. The exemple I am showing is using Clarity and is a modal but I also have the issue on the same component but outside the modal so I am pretty sure the modal is not involved.

HTML :

```
<clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="openModal">
<h3 class="modal-title">Confirmation d'importation</h3>
<div class="modal-body" *ngIf="parsedCsv !== undefined">
    <p>Vérifiez que les colonnes correspondent bien aux informations.</p>
    <div class="list" *ngFor="let column of sampleArrayDisplay.slice(0,1)">
        <div class="box display" *ngFor="let sample of column">
            <p>{{sample}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list" *ngFor="let column of sampleArrayDisplay.slice(1, 10)">
        <div class="box display box-data" *ngFor="let data of column">{{data}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="openModal = false">Annuler</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onImport()">Importer</button>
</div>
```

SCSS :

```
.list {
 max-width: 100%;
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
 min-height: 60px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 4px;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.box {
 width: 100px;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 20px 10px;
 border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 cursor: move;
 background: white;
 font-size: 14px;
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-basis: 0;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Posting images is considered a bad practice in SO. Could you post the code which you are using?

Comment: Added some snippets for clarification